# Why does VB6 make trivial changes to object size properties?

Tags: vb6

Quite often the VB6 IDE makes small, seemingly pointless changes to the sizes of things in forms.

Here's an example (in *diff* format, red lines have been replaced by green):

[image]

These are all related to the "size" of something.

Why does this occur? It clogs up source control procedures with nuisance lines. Is there any way to prevent it?

Although you might think these changes would have a visible effect, they really seem not to which seems odd.

Comment: Smells like a problem caused by flippity-flopping developer client system DPI settings.  I can't think of anything else that would make Windows hunt for font sizes like that.

Comment: This happens if two or more developers with different system DPI work on the same form.

Comment: @Bob77, & wqw thanks... is there any way to avoid this other than the DPI settings themselves? And how does one know what the "right" values are??

Comment: @DaveInCaz: there is no right values.  There are only values that work.  I suggest using a good diff tool, and don’t commit changes that aren’t deliberate.  Takes discipline, but you get consistent results.

Comment: @jmoreno thanks, that is actually exactly what we do, makes the history more intelligible.